# Play store formatting: app vs web

Tags: android, formatting, google-play

On the play store app my [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.akash.medicine) description looks quite nice. On the web however it looks really wrong. The bold looks too bold which I can live with, but the spacing is off. You need two line breaks to achieve the same thing as you can see on the play store. However this in turn would mess up the formatting on the play store app. Any advice on how to do this? I'm thinking `<br>` might help but some sources say that it doesn't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried out `<br />` and it worked. All you have to do is write it like this:

```
This is a line <br />

This is the next line
```

This results in proper formatting in both the app and web.

Comment: Do you know perhaps how to put indentation?